# Is there a way to return a 3D list from embedded Python back to ECL?

Tags: python, rgb, hpcc-ecl, hpcc

I have a 2D array in Python which I want to return back to ELC, for further usage.
The recordset is of the following format

```
layout:=RECORD
      INTEGER RED;
      INTEGER GREEN;
      INTEGER BLUE;
END;
```

The no. of records approximate to around 640000, which when I attempt to return to ELC and display, gives the following error:

```
Dataset too large to output to workunit(limit is set to 10)megabytes
```

Is there any method to change the output limit of a workunit?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Shashank,

RGB values tend to each usually be in the range of 0-255 (in ECL, that means an UNSIGNED1 -- an unsigned 1-byte integer type), and the INTEGER type you're using defaults to an 8-byte signed integer type.

So, if you change your return types from your Python code to 1-byte unsigned RGB values you should reduce the total return size to an eighth of the previous. Since 640000 recs * 3 bytes each = 1.92Mb total returned data (considerably smaller than the 10Mb error message you're getting), just doing this should hopefully solve your problem.

HTH,

Richard

Comment: When I try to convert to 1-bit unsigned data in Python, it is converted into a numpy.uint8, which I'm unable to return to ECL. It only takes basic data types

Comment: "It only takes basic data types" -- please define "It" in this context -- does Python not allow you to return uint8? Or do you think ECL won't accept an UNSIGNED1 as a return value? I ask, because in ECL an UNSIGNED1 is a "basic data type" so please expand with more details on your problem.

Comment: Shashank, you can use a simple cast from uint8 to int8, or even just to int. See this embedded python code that creates a uint8 number, converts it to int and returns it to ECL:
UNSIGNED IntToECL () := EMBED(Python)
    import numpy
    u_number = numpy.uint8(8)
    number = numpy.int(u_number)
    return(number)
ENDEMBED;

I'm defining the function type as UNSIGNED, but could be UNSIGNEDn. It means that python will provide an INT type, matching the UNSIGNED/INTEGER ECL types. Since I'm using UNSIGNED on the function definition, that's the type used after the python function return.